# How do I add a "unlock ring" like UI to my project?

Tags: android, user-interface

I searched the last hour for any information on how to implement a UI widget that looks similar to the "unlock ring" (see screenshot below).

I did not find any documentation nor libraries that provide such a UI, although I have seen some apps that use the same ring-style (eg the native caller screen) or at least similar styles (eg the alarm clock "Timely").

Are there any libraries or APIs for implementing such a style? Thank you!

[image: screenshot]

Comment: When you [searched the Android Arsenal for `ring`](https://android-arsenal.com/search?q=ring), what did you learn?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there are two libraries out there that provide such a function:

- https://github.com/nadavfima/GlowPadView
- https://github.com/frakbot/GlowPadBackport